How to connect to "upstands" on the PCB without soldering?
I've got two items of the same model number, but one of them has a Phoenix type terminal on the PCB for the connection. See photo below.

The other one has "upstands" poking out of the PCB.

How can I connect to the upstands without soldering on a Phoenix type terminal or soldering directly to the upstands? Is there some sort of push fit or mechanically fixed connector that would work?

"Is there some sort of push fit ... connector that would work" - yes, and you already have some of them. All of the black connectors in your 1st image will pull off the pins ("upstands") on the board, as will the blue connector in your 2nd picture.

Whilst those connects were made by a Phoenix subsidiary, the term ‘Phoenix connector’ suggests the green plug in screw terminal type like their MSTB series.

The PCBs are identical.
They both have a connectors for a detachable screw terminal.
The other PCB just has the detachable PCB terminal block attached and the other one has it detached.

thanks, i can find detachable PCB terminal blocks online, but they all seem to have the upstands coming out of the terminal, rather than accepting upstands from a PCB, see here - https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/pcb-terminal-blocks/8970736 . Is that the correct type of product i should be looking for ?

@user27511 No, you need to look for products that look like what you already have on your power supply. Try to detach any of the three terminal blocks on the two supplies.

They are this sort of thing, e.g. from Keystone
